# Why does my php code with cookies not work correctly?

Tags: php, cookies

Now I am messing around with code. I am new at coding in PHP. I wanted to learn cookies and I thought that it would be cool to redirect the person after 5 seconds when they first come to my site but then not do it again the next time but just instantly redirect them. I though I could use cookies but it is not working for me. Can you please help me find out what is wrong with my code.

```
<?php 


$checker_name = "redirect_check";
$checker_value = "0";

setcookie($checker_name, $checker_value, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');


if(!isset($_COOKIE[$checker_name])) {
    print 'Cookie Not Found';
} else {
if($_COOKIE[$checker_name] == "0") {
    print 'Please Wait';
    unset($_COOKIE[$checker_name]);
    setcookie($checker_name, '1', time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
    header( "refresh:5;url=http://www.cubedsoftware.com/home" );
    die();
} else {
    header('Location: home');
    die();
}}   ?>
```

Comment: You can't set and check cookies at the same page in php. Either go to a second page to read it or you have to refresh the page

Comment: You can add this line before the setcookie line `if(!isset($_COOKIE[$checker_name]))` this makes it work with refresh. If you don't have that line the browser will set a new cookie and disable read possibilities. But if you check for cookie and not set it, you can read it

Answer (score 0):

When you set a cookie it will be send to the browser along with the HTTP Response. The browser then will include the cookie with each new HTTP Request to that domain.

The `$_COOKIE` superglobal will contain whatever is sent over from the browser. Since no HTTP request has been made by the time the following line gets executed:

`if(!isset($_COOKIE[$checker_name])) {`

the `$_COOKIE` superglobal will be empty.

Instead of printing `Cookie not found` when not finding a cookie you should generate one and make the user wait for 5 seconds (the default behavior for a first time visitor according to what you want to achieve)

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$checker_name])) {
    $checker_value = 1;
    setcookie($checker_name, $checker_value, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
}
```

By setting `$checker_value` to 1 you ensure that next time the user won't have to wait

Answer (score 0):

You can't set and check cookies at the same page in php. Either go to a second page to read it or you have to refresh the page.

You can add this line before the setcookie line

`if(!isset($_COOKIE[$checker_name]))`

this makes it work with refresh.
If you don't have that line the browser will set a new cookie and disable read possibilities.
But if you check for cookie and not set it, you can read it.

Hope that makes sense.